# Do the Jews of Marakkesh have a particular Nusach?

Tags: tefilla, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, nuschaot, communities

Is there a particular Siddur or Nusach HaTefilla that is used by the Jews (and their descendants) of Marakkesh (*alt. sp.* Marrakech), Moroccco? Is it in print and available?

Comment: Is there any reason you'd assume it would be different from the normal Moroccan nusach?

Comment: This link (http://www.wslibrary.net/sifria/he/tephila/6835-ahavat-haqadmonim-sidur_mahadurat-hameir.html) provides a Siddur for the community of Fez (also in Morocco) and this link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kn7suw1hLfQ) seems to provide a basis for a unique Nusach for Marrakesh.

Answer (score 1):

see [here](http://www.onthederekh.org/prayer-books.html) and [here](https://www.korenpub.com/koren_en_usd/avoteinu-siddur.html) for Moroccan Siddur. This is the standard nusach used by the Moroccan communities.

Comment: And how do you know that the Jewish communities in Merrakesh use the standard Moroccan nusach?